# Digitalize old diagrams and tables

Tags: ocr

Reading old science papers I found nomograms with chemical content, as for my example a nomogram of sulfuric acid and its enthalpy:
[image]

Is there a possibility to mathematical correctly digitalize this nomogram if one does not have the correct table of numbers which created it?

My approach would be "giving" a program the grid and its values and then "read" the curvature of the individual data.

Is this possible or am I here on the wrong forum for such a question?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use tesseract-ocr. This tool is giving you ejected text and box boundaries of each word/letter. They might solve your problem, you can try this approach.

I used this tool to detect, wether words belong to same line, are on the same level on the page.